ubuntu 24.01 snapd updating daily for the last 3 days?
Snap is proposing updates to Snapd & Desktop integration for several days. The updates are for the same packages that are presently installed. I have reinstalled and the next day snap store comes back with the same update

"I have reinstalled" what did you reinstall? What update does it keep coming back with? Please [edit] your question accordingly. Don't add to the comment trail (that's for us to ask you questions). You might also wish to read [ask]

Thank Graham for the reply. Issue resolved. Due to me wishing to recieve.prerelease updates...I recieved notice on all new code....the reinstall concerned SNAPD....which I realized had multiple commints in the last several days.
